# PostgreSQL query using table without permission

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am dealing with a remote data base where I have permission to only access specific tables.

The relevant data has the form:

```
CREATE TABLE t_a(v_a VARCHAR(32), v_b VARCHAR(32));
CREATE TABLE t_b(v_b VARCHAR(32), v_c VARCHAR(32));

INSERT INTO t_a VALUES ('one', 'abc1');
INSERT INTO t_a VALUES ('two', 'abc2');
INSERT INTO t_a VALUES ('three', 'abc3');

INSERT INTO t_b VALUES ('abc1', 'eins');
INSERT INTO t_b VALUES ('abc2', 'zwei');
INSERT INTO t_b VALUES ('abc3', 'drei');
```

My query looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (v_a) v_a, v_c FROM t_a, t_b WHERE t_a.v_b = t_b=v_b;
```

Now the actual question: Can I somehow get the same information without permission to read from `t_b`? Is there another approach I could try?

**EDIT**

Sadly, I do not have the rights to change the permissions. My line of thought was that since I only want to have an association between `v_a` and `v_c`, I could get away with not selecting any columns from `t_b`. After a bit more thinking, I can see why this should not be allowed by the permission system - after all, I try to read *some* information from `t_b`.

I was also hoping that maybe there are different permission layers where one of them permits non-selecting queries.

Comment: Do you mean you want to include t_b in a query even though you do not have read permission on it? What kind of database system would allow that?

Comment: Did you `GRANT` access on the table to `PUBLIC` or to some user/role? If not, then only the owner can access it.

Comment: Not related but: using `distinct on` without specifying an `order by` is not such a good idea

Comment: @harmic, Craig Ringer: I cannot change the permission of the data base. I edited the question to give more info on my reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create that table with a different account that either owns it or has been GRANTED read to the table. You than create a stored function created by the same account that owns or has rights to read the table.  GRANT EXECUTE to the new function to you personal account that doesn't have rights to the table. Execute the new function and you can get at the data. This is called SECURITY DEFINER and more can be read here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createfunction.html

With this setup your account won't have access to the table directly, like by doing select * from your_table. You can only get to it via the function. Same can be done with views and is how a lot of database designs setup access to tables. The function or view is the public interface

Comment: I think this would actually be the kind of permission level I mentioned in my edit. Thanks for the link!